# Basic SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am just beginning an SQL class and am having issues with one of the problems I must do. 
The question is

Use the IN operator to list the part number and part description of each part in item class AP or SG.

What I have for the answer is

```
SELECT PART_NUM, DESCRIPTION
FROM PART
WHERE CLASS IN (AP,  SG);
```

If I try to run that it states that SG is an invalid identifier. But if I view the table there are classes that = both ap and sg. does anyone have any assistance as to what I am doing incorrectly? Thanks for your time

Comment: I feel ridiculous, thank you that definitely made it work

Comment: just other people looking at it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the values 'AP','SG' as they are chars.

... in ('AP','SG')

Answer (score 3):

if class is an attribute of type `varchar2` o `varchar` you should run sql like this

```
SELECT PART_NUM, DESCRIPTION

FROM PART

WHERE CLASS IN ('AP', 'SG');
```

Notice that putting a `'` on each element

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing quotes - try:

WHERE CLASS IN ('AP', 'SG');

Answer (score 0):

Only **int** values can be written without quotes for **char and varchar** datatypes, you need to use quotes and hence the values AP and SG must be provided in quotes like below :

```
SELECT PART_NUM, DESCRIPTION  
FROM PART  
WHERE CLASS IN ('AP','SG');
```